# how do you spool from a stored procedure that is executed through a database link?

Tags: unix, plsql, database, spool, database-link

I am using a UNIX script to run sql code that kicks off a stored procedure via database link.  I can get the procedure to complete successfully, however none of the DBMS outputs are spooled to the SPOOL file indicated.

SQL within UNIX:

```
set feedback off;
set linesize 500;
set serveroutput on size 1000000;
set serveroutput on format wrapped;
spool $SQLspool;

whenever oserror exit;
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;

DECLARE

retcode integer :=0;

BEGIN

owner.procedure@db;

dbms_output.put_line('');
dbms_output.put_line('return code: ' || retcode);
dbms_output.put_line('');


EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE;  

END;
/
EXIT;
```

---

SPOOLFILE CONTENTS:

```
return code: 0
```

---

I list a bunch of DMBS outputs within the stored procedure but nothing is written to the spool file.

How can I get it to output to the spool file?

I tried to have IN OUT variables, but because the procedure contains COMMITs it errors out with the parameters since it is going through the DB Link...

Comment: Do you see the output from owner.procedure@db in SQL*PLUS, and it is not getting written to the spool file. Or is the output simply not displayed?

Comment: did you check that there are no "dbms_output.disable" calls in the procedure ?

Comment: @ Shannon Severance:so the only dbms output I'm getting is from the unix script which "return code: 0"  None of the output is getting stored to the spool file indicated from the stored procedure. 
@ A.B.Cade:  there is no such calls in the procedure.  The stored procedure is a simple delete statement with a loop committing every 10k rows.

Answer (score 0):

The output for PUT and PUT_LINE is buffered. From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#sthref4434)
:

> SQL*Plus does not display DBMS_OUTPUT messages until the PL/SQL program completes. There is no mechanism for flushing the DBMS_OUTPUT buffers within the PL/SQL program.

So, if you are looking to stream responses you are going to need to write a small program which does not buffer the output.